# Is there an easy way to convert rows in BigQuery to JSON?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to reduce my rows in my BigQuery Table to JSON string.
Is there a quick way to do this in standard SQL?

I thought about calling js with User-defined Function, but it forces me to declare the input type of the UDF so I can't generalize this function.

Comment: 1) based on your wording it looks to me as a one time task that you need to accomplish. why you need to generalize it? 2) are you limited to making it as a pure query or you use some client in your practice (like python, go, etc.) that you can easily employ for this?

Comment: @mikhail-berlyant 1) We are trying to migrate our scattered data to bigquery and combining some of the data as JSON is our current plan. So unless using JSON is a terrible idea.. generalizing shouldn't be a bad idea. 2) If I understand your question correctly, it would be nice to self-contain bigquery stuff

Comment: 1) is your "scattered" data already in BigQuery or somewhere else? 2) do you understand/accept consequences of combining your data into JSON String. You most likely then will be paying higher price when query it.

Comment: @mikhail-berlyant 1) The data I am trying to reduce is already on BigQuery. I am essentially creating a view.  2) Yes/No. Some of the data have variable number of data types so I am thinking using JSON string would allow it to be flexible. I am assuming when you say 'price' you are referring to performance and usability?

Comment: i was referencing $ amount. BigQuery is columnar, so you are being billed for only columns you are referencing in your query. If you combine multiple fields(columns) into one column - you are will be paying for whole column even if you will be interested in very narrow path

Comment: I updated my answer, by the way, since it's possible just to use `TO_JSON_STRING` directly rather than using a UDF.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is now possible using [`TO_JSON_STRING`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#to_json_string), which can also help when you want to [pass a row from your table to a JavaScript UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44031989/6253347).

```
#standardSQL
WITH MyTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS x, 'foo' AS y, true AS z UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'bar', false
)
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t) AS json
FROM MyTable AS t;
```

Comment: Error: TypeError: s.stringify is not a function at structasjson(STRUCT<x STRING, y STRING>) line 1, columns 9-10

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out--it should be `JSON.stringify(s);`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Brossard, wow dude this was the fastest response I ever got on SO

Comment: Ha ha the timing worked out well I guess. I realized that the OP can now use `TO_JSON_STRING` to address his question, but if you want to convert a struct to JSON within a JavaScript UDF, you can still use `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: It's not available yet :( I tried to describe it as well as I could in http://stackoverflow.com/a/44031989/6253347, but keep an eye on the [BigQuery release notes](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes) for the "real" documentation.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to glue together all of the rows quickly into a JSON block, you can do something like:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT("[", STRING_AGG(TO_JSON_STRING(t), ","), "]")
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

This will produce a table with 1 row that contains a complete JSON blob summarizing the entire table.