# How can I pass a row from my table to a UDF without specifying the complete type?

Tags: google-bigquery

Let's say that I want to do some processing on a table (such as the [sample Github commits](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/bigquery-public-data:github_repos.sample_commits?tab=schema)) that has a nested structure using a [JavaScript UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#external-udf-structure). I may want to change the fields that I look at in the UDF as I iterate on its implementation, so I decide just to pass entire rows from the table to it. My UDF ends up looking something like this:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION GetCommitStats(
  input STRUCT<commit STRING, tree STRING, parent ARRAY<STRING>,
               author STRUCT<name STRING, email STRING, ...>>)
  RETURNS STRUCT<
    parent ARRAY<STRING>,
    author_name STRING,
    diff_count INT64>
  LANGUAGE js AS """
[UDF content here]
""";
```

Then I call the function with a query such as:

```
SELECT GetCommitStats(t).*
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.sample_commits` AS t;
```

The most cumbersome part of the UDF declaration is the input struct, since I have to include all of the nested fields and their types. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`TO_JSON_STRING`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#to_json_string) to convert arbitrary structs and arrays to JSON, then parse it inside your UDF into an object for further processing. For example,

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION GetCommitStats(json_str STRING)
  RETURNS STRUCT<
    parent ARRAY<STRING>,
    author_name STRING,
    diff_count INT64>
  LANGUAGE js AS """
var row = JSON.parse(json_str);
var result = new Object();
result['parent'] = row.parent;
result['author_name'] = row.author.name;
result['diff_count'] = row.difference.length;
return result;
""";

SELECT GetCommitStats(TO_JSON_STRING(t)).*
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.sample_commits` AS t;
```

If you want to cut down on the number of columns that are scanned, you can pass a struct of the relevant columns to `TO_JSON_STRING` instead:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION GetCommitStats(json_str STRING)
  RETURNS STRUCT<
    parent ARRAY<STRING>,
    author_name STRING,
    diff_count INT64>
  LANGUAGE js AS """
var row = JSON.parse(json_str);
var result = new Object();
result['parent'] = row.parent;
result['author_name'] = row.author.name;
result['diff_count'] = row.difference.length;
return result;
""";

SELECT
  GetCommitStats(TO_JSON_STRING(
    STRUCT(parent, author, difference)
  )).*
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.sample_commits`;
```

Comment: How did you discover all that valuable info without official documentation?

Comment: Is there a legacy sql solution?

Comment: No. The BigQuery team is prioritizing standard SQL for all new feature development.